# Color Addition in Android

Tags: c#, android, colors

How is color addition done in android? For my pathtracer i am storing a Color but i didn't find a way to get the r,g,b values back.

I think if i want to get red i do this:

```
returnColor.red(0)
```

but it doesn't work.

Since i work more with android in the last week i do more and more think why stuff is made so complicated in android? In C# you just add the r,g,b values and you don't get an integer back if you type

```
Color.White
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the static method red of the Color class:

```
int red = Color.red(color)
```

The same class has the `argb` method that allows you to get the int representing your color, through the 4 components. E.g.

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int)) you can find the documentation

Comment: In pathtracing i trace a ray through scene. My last steps in my trace function:

`
        int c = hitObject.color * returnColor;

        c /= depth;

        return c;
`
mainloop

`
                        int c = 0;
                        for(int i = 0; i < RAYS_PER_PIXEL; i++){
                            int color = Trace(ray, 1);
                            c += color;
                        }

                        c /= RAYS_PER_PIXEL;

                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(c);
                        canvas.drawPoint(x,y,paint);
`

Comment: I see, do you want to retrieve the value of red/blue/green from `c`?

Comment: `int red = Color.red(c)`, `int green = Color.green(c)`, `int blue = Color.blue(c)`

Comment: but if i want to multiply colors do i have to divide by 255 to get the average color?